# How to hide the form that holds the user control in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls

I am making a system using C# and I am just new to using the User Control with the forms. So what I wanted to do is to hide the current form that holds the user control using the button placed in the user control. Is there any way to do this? I need the code for the button in user control.

Additional Details:

I have the Form1 in which a user control is docked to it, the user control is named as UserControl1 and it has a button, I want that button to open another form which is Form2 and in the process is to  hide the Form1 that holds the UserControl1.

Comment: This would be a better question if you told us about your use case.  Based on your description, you're probably not going about this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your UserControl:

```
this.ParentForm.Close();
```

About ParentForm: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ContainerControl_ParentForm

About Close: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-6.0